# Polynomial expectations of generic distributions

Tags: evaluation, probability-or-statistics, symbolic

**Summary**

*Polynomial expectations depend only moments and cross moments of a multivariate distribution. I would like to use `Expectation` to compute polynomial expectations for generic distribution of which only the necessary moments are specified.*

**Some details**

I would like to compute polynomial exectations with the function `Expectation` for variables distributed according to a generic distribution. Here is a toy example:

```
In[139]:= ClearAll[myDist]

myDist /: Moment[myDist[mu_, var_], 1] := mu
myDist /: Moment[myDist[mu_, var_], 2] := Moment[myDist[mu, var], 1]^2 + var
myDist /: Moment[myDist[0, var_], 4] := 
 Cumulant[myDist[0, var], 4] + 2 Moment[myDist[0, var], 2]
myDist /: Moment[myDist[0, var_], 3] := 0
```

This few lines provide enough information about the distribution `myDist` so that Mathematica can compute

```
In[144]:= Expectation[2 x^2, x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], Method -> "Moment"]
Expectation[2 x^4, x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], Method -> "Moment"]

Out[144]= 2 s^2

Out[145]= 2 (2 s^2 + Cumulant[myDist[0, s^2], 4])
```

I would like to carry out similar calculations with several random variables. For example.

```
In[147]:= ClearAll[a, b, x, y]
Expectation[
 a x + b y, {x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], 
  y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"]
Expectation[(a x + b y)^2, {x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], 
  y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"]

Out[148]= Expectation[
 a x + b y, {x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], 
  y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"]

Out[149]= Expectation[(a x + b y)^2, {x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], 
  y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"]
```

In this case Mathematica doesn't carry out the computation, even though it has all the information to do so. Namely

1. `x` and `y` are independent (this is implied in the specification `{x\[Distributed]myDist[0,s^2],y\[Distributed]myDist[0,s^2]}`, according to the definition of `Expectation`);
2. the result is completely determined by the first and second moment of `x` and `y` (Provided).

One of the problems is that `Expectation` doesn't  know (or it is pre-emped by some other rule or evaluation)

```
In[153]:= Expectation[
  a x + b y, {x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], 
   y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"] ===

 a Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], Method -> "Moment"] + 
  b Expectation[y, y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], Method -> "Moment"]

Out[153]= False
```

Notice that all-is-well when the distribution is one that Mathematica knows

```
In[166]:= Expectation[
 a x + b y, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s^2], 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"]

Out[166]= 0
```

One possible solution is to define an operator such as `myExpectation` that knows/uses linearity properties of the mathematical expectation, but I would rather not reinvent the wheel and leverage the power of the built in symbol `Expectation` (for example specializing a result to one of the built in distributions) as well as the ease with it deals with higher momenta and cumulants.
I tried (with no success)

1. using `ProductDistribution[{myDist[], 2}]` instead of       
   `{x\[Distributed]myDist[0,s^2],y\[Distributed]myDist[0,s^2]}`;
2. definiting a generic distribution as suggested (here) with the symbol `ProbabilityDistribution`. In this case the delayed `UpValues` for the moments cannot be set.

Indeed

```
 myDist2[mu_, var_] =
 ProbabilityDistribution[myDistPDF[x, mu, var], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
myDist2 /: Moment[myDist[mu_, var_], 1] := mu

Out[164]= ProbabilityDistribution[
 myDistPDF[\[FormalX], mu, var], {\[FormalX], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

During evaluation of In[164]:= TagSetDelayed::tagnf: Tag myDist2 not found in Moment[ProbabilityDistribution[myDistPDF[\[FormalX],mu_,var_],{\[FormalX],-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}],1]. >>

Out[165]= $Failed
```

If a `HoldPattern` the left-hand-side of the moment delayed assignment, the command executes with no error, but it the information won't be used by `Expectation`. The reason for this is that `Expectation` first evaluates its arguments and `myDist2` evaluated to

```
ProbabilityDistribution[myDistPDF[\[FormalX],mu,var],{\[FormalX],-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

and the upvalues of `myDist` are  from then on "invisible" to `Expectation`.

Some related question on how to define an arbitrary distributions are 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3525337/986817) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!starred/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/1fNZX2qlctw).

Comment: does the answer below not answer your question?

Comment: @chris, sorry for the late replay. I meant to let it sit for a while hoping to get a less "disruptive" answer and forgot to check back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you add

```
myDist /: Moment[myDist[mu_, var_], 0] := 1
```

The following (which is risky as it messes up with built in definitions) would 
work

```
freeQ[a_, b_] := FreeQ[a, b] /; Length[b] <= 1
freeQ[a_, b_] := And @@ Map[FreeQ[a, #] &, b] /; Length[b] > 1

Unprotect[Expectation];
Expectation[a__, b__, c__] := 
       Map[Expectation[#, b, c] &, a // Expand] /; Head[Expand[a]] == Plus
Expectation[a_ z_, b_, c__] := 
       a Expectation[z, b, c] /; freeQ[a, b /. u_ \[Distributed] _ -> u]
Expectation[a_ , {b__, c__}, d__] := 
       Expectation[a, b, d] /; freeQ[a, c /. u_ \[Distributed] _ -> u]
Expectation[a1_ a2_ , {b1__, b2__}, c__] := 
Expectation[a1, b1, c] Expectation[a2, b2, c] /; 
      (freeQ[a2, b1 /. u_ \[Distributed] _ -> u] && 
       freeQ[a1, b2 /. u_ \[Distributed] _ -> u] )
Expectation[a_ , {b_, c_}, d__] := 
       Expectation[a, c, d] /; freeQ[a, b /. u_ \[Distributed] _ -> u]
Protect[Expectation];
```

e.g.

```
 Expectation[(a x + b y)^2, {x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], 
 y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"]
```

(* a^2 s^2+b^2 s^2 *)

```
 Expectation[(a x + b y)^3, {x \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2], 
 y \[Distributed] myDist[0, s^2]}, Method -> "Moment"]
```

(* 0 *)

Once again this is risky and I have not checked all possible edge effects ! :-)